# ML.NET how to detect a model is missing from the PredictionEnginePool

Tags: ml.net

I'm trying to check if a model exists in the PredictionEnginePool by calling predictionEnginePool.GetModel(modelName: "ModelA") but I get an exception saying the model is not in the Dictionary even though I pass in the correct model name specified during creation.

Is this the right way to look for a model or is there a better way?

Comment: Are you calling this from a web app? If so there is the Microsoft.Extensions.ML package you can use. Here's the documentation on it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/serve-model-web-api-ml-net

Comment: I’m well aware of this doc. I train a new model at runtime when the prediction engine pool had already past setup in startup.cs. I want to check if the model had already been loaded or not before making a prediction.

Answer (score 0):

CEO, I don't think there's currently a way to check if a model has been loaded or not. I recommend submitting an issue as a suggestion to the ML.NET repo. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning